# What's the most efficient way to sort a Text value?

Tags: sorting, haskell

If I have a `Data.Text` value that I want to sort, should I just unpack it to a `String` and use `sort` or some other function on it? It seems like it would be tough to write a fast sorting function for Text values when cons and append are both O(n).

Comment: Do you mean to ask about sorting a list of `Text` values instead, in which case the cost of constructing `Text` values is irrelevant?

Comment: No, I mean sorting a Text value in the same way you would sort a string. Like reading some text from a file and then sorting it.

Comment: But there you're still sorting a *list* of strings, with each string being a line of the file.  If you actually apply `sort` to a `String`, you get something like `"0014555AAAABBQ..."`; is that really what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. I'm writing some text compression algorithms for Haskell practice, and I'm trying to write the Burrows-Wheeler Transform, which requires sorting.

Comment: Sorting unicode data is one of the silliest things I've ever heard of. It sort of half-works for english text. It fails miserably for a great deal of what's in unicode.

Comment: Well this is just for practice/fun. I could use Bytestrings, I just figured if I was going to write a text compression algorithm then it might as well work on whatever text I can find, not just ascii.

Comment: If you're using Burrows-Wheeler then you want to work over a fixed alphabet, not necessarily ASCII. You can do it over raw bytes, if you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "sorting" `Text`. Much of the value of the `Text` type is tied up in it handling weird human language inconsistencies correctly. Probably the best way to sort while taking those variants into account is to use the `text-icu`

```
import           Data.Text.ICU
import qualified Data.Text     as T

-- | Uses the Unicode Collation Algorithm. Others can be chosen by picking 
-- something other than `uca` as your Collator.
sortText :: [T.Text] -> [T.Text]
sortText = sortBy (sortKey uca)
```

If you do what you suggested in your question—unpack to a string then compare strings by lexicographic character order—you'll possibly be slower (`String` is a much bulkier type than `Text`) but you'll certainly open up possibilities of weird sort orders and weird re-packing if you have Unicode `Text` values.

Comment: Based on the comments, Data.Text is probably not what I want to be using for my particular problem, but this does look like the best way to sort unicode if you need to.